# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet&

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying update marks through a dialog box.but it is showing error.

This is my POJO class called Student, I have created one table for that to update marks.

```
@Entity
public class Student 
{
    @Id
    private int sid;
    @Column(length=10)
    private String sname;
    private int marks;
    @Version
    private int verson;
    public int getSid() {
        return sid;
    }
    public void setSid(int sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }
    public String getsname() {
        return sname;
    }
    public void setsname(String sName) {
        this.sname = sName;
    }
    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }
    public int getVerson() {
        return verson;
    }
    public void setVerson(int verson) {
        this.verson = verson;
    }

}
```

This is my main class

```
public class ClientOfUser1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Configuration conf=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    ServiceRegistry registry=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();
    SessionFactory factory=conf.buildSessionFactory(registry);
    Session session=factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
    Student s=(Student)session.get(Student.class, 101);
    String str=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter marks of (User1)");
    int m= Integer.parseInt(str);
    s.setMarks(m);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    factory.close();
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to execute this, it is showing another error also the error is *"STUDENT0_"."VERSON": invalid identifier*

Comment: Please post the relevant exception stacktraces.

Comment: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
 at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
 at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExc
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(

Comment: Is it the full error message?

Comment: **Edit** your question, don't use comments to add pertinent information. And that doesn't look like the full exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

There's too little information in the question. Please put the full error message, the structure of your database table, etc.

But... I'll take a guess, you have a typo...

Here you're missing an I:

> "STUDENT0_"."VERSON": invalid identifier

which comes from:

> ```
> private int verson;
> ```

and respective setters/getters.

And I bet your database table has a column called `VERSION`.

Comment: i have version column in my table

Comment: @sai OK. Then it's not matching the field/property name as indicated here.

Comment: Later I changed that spelling.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

in application.properties

Otherwise explicitly specify studaent table name and schema name with @Table annotation

```
@Table(schema="...", name="...")
```